# Custom Image scroller in Android

Tags: android-layout, android

I am developing an application where most of the UI's are custom GUI's. As I am a newbie to Android, I find myself difficult to make them work. Now I have to develop a component that will be used as image scroller, with indicator  and previous and next button to control them. I have attached the image below. can anyone suggest me how to do with it.

[image]

I also got the link to the android view page indicator, but that takes whole of my screen. How do i customize for the best fit to my requirement.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [paginated gallery](https://github.com/sfarooq/PaginatedGallery) it is helpful for you..

Comment: i hope it will help ful @smiley